# Installing megatools Package on 14.04

Tags: 14.04

https://github.com/megous/megatools

Build instructions state:

```
On Debian, Ubuntu:

  apt-get -y install build-essential libglib2.0-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libgirepository1.0-dev
```

However when attempting to install on 14.04 lts I get the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.44.1-1.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1)
                  Depends: libpcre3-dev (>= 1:8.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying to build it without, I receive an error that the glib version is to low:
`configure: error: Glib 2.32.0 or later is required to build megatools`
Is there any way to fix it?
Thanks

As requested:

```
libglib2.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.40.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.40.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.40.0-2 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you add any Third Party repositories?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-dev`

Comment: [Edit] your question again, I need the output of `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0`

Answer (score 0):

The package `libglib2.0-dev (2.40.0-2)` in the standard [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglib2.0-dev) depends on `libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.0-2)`. The `=` means, exactly this version.

Your problem is, you have a added a PPA to your system, which provides a newer version. You need to remove this PPA.

Which PPA it is, that can you see with the command

```
apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0
```

Taken from your edited question, remove the digitalocean PPA.

Comment: So I should remove the digitalocean PPA?

Comment: Is libglib the same as Glib? As i have v2.44 and only Glib 2.32.0 or later is required to build

Comment: Exactly,v remove this PPA

Comment: Glib is libglib. The first is the name, the second the package name in the software repositories

Comment: how come I get the error Glib 2.32.0 or later is required to build if i have version 2.44 already?

Comment: `libglib2.0-dev` depends exactly on 2.40 and not 2.44. Maybe you should ask the PPA maintainer.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)